# IoC with AutoMapper Profile using Autofac

Tags: automapper

I have been using AutoMapper for some time now. I have a profile setup like so:

```
public class ViewModelAutoMapperConfiguration : Profile
    {
        protected override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "ViewModel"; }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            AddFormatter<HtmlEncoderFormatter>();
            CreateMap<IUser, UserViewModel>();

        }
    }
```

I add this to the mapper using the following call:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<ViewModelAutoMapperConfiguration>());
```

However, I now want to pass a dependency into the `ViewModelAutoMapperConfiguration` constructor using IoC. I am using Autofac. I have been reading through the article here: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/05/11/automapper-and-ioc.aspx but I can't see how this would work with Profiles.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a way of doing it by using an overload of `AddProfile`. There is an overload that takes an instance of a profile, so I can resolve the instance before passing it into the `AddProfile` method.

Answer (score 0):

A customer of mine was wondering the same thing as [DownChapel and his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403906/352640) triggered me in writing some sample application.

What I've done is the following.
First retrieve all `Profile` types from the asseblies and register them in the IoC container (I'm using Autofac).

```
var loadedProfiles = RetrieveProfiles();
containerBuilder.RegisterTypes(loadedProfiles.ToArray());
```

While registering the AutoMapper configuration I'm resolving all of the `Profile` types and resolve an instance from them.

```
private static void RegisterAutoMapper(IContainer container, IEnumerable<Type> loadedProfiles)
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve);
        foreach (var profile in loadedProfiles)
        {
             var resolvedProfile = container.Resolve(profile) as Profile;
             cfg.AddProfile(resolvedProfile);
        }
    });
}
```

This way your IoC-framework (Autofac) will resolve all dependencies of the `Profile`, so it can have dependencies.

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile(IConvertor convertor)
    {
        CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Identifier))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => convertor.Execute(src.SomeText)))
            ;
    }
}
```

The complete sample application can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Jandev/AutoMapperDependencyInjection), but most of the important code is shared over here.