# Automapper and Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, automapper-3

I am trying to get Automapper to play nice with Autofac in an ASP.Net MVC application.

I have followed the instructions in the answer to this: [Autofac 3 and Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615607/autofac-3-and-automapper/14676431#14676431)

However it fails on the first call to `_mapper.Map<>(...)`

Autofac is setup like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<EntityMappingProfile>().As<Profile>();

builder.Register(ctx => new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .SingleInstance()
    .OnActivating(x =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in x.Context.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
        {
            x.Instance.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });

builder.RegisterType<MappingEngine>().As<IMappingEngine>();
```

and then in my business layer I have a service like this:

```
public class LinkService : ILinkService
{
    private readonly ILinkRepository _linkRepository;
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mapper;
    public LinkService(ILinkRepository linkRepository, IMappingEngine mapper)
    {
        _linkRepository = linkRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;

    }

    public IEnumerable<LinkEntity> Get()
    {
        var links = _linkRepository.Get().ToList();
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Link>, IEnumerable<LinkEntity>>(links);
    }

    public LinkEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        var link = _linkRepository.GetById(id);
        return _mapper.Map<Link, LinkEntity>(link);
    }
}
```

The call to `_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Link>, IEnumerable<LinkEntity>>`
fails with:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing creating Mapper, create map Link to LinkEntity in EntityMappingProfile:

```
  internal class EntityMappingProfile :Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.Configure();
        this.CreateMap<Link, LinkEntity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I should have shown that, my mapping profile looks just like that. (with all my other maps too)

Comment: Can you put the breakpoint at line this.CreateMap<Link, LinkEntity>(); and debug to see if it's hit? as my testing, it's working fine

Comment: ahh I found the issue..

I had Mapper.CreateMap<>...

I changed this it this.CreateMap<> and it now all works fine :) Thanks